# Tag an item based off nearest player’s name

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making an adventure map on Minecraft Bedrock, and I’m having a bit of an issue. What I’m trying to do is make snowballs act as special ender pearls that only teleport you when they hit certain blocks (grapple points, basically) and that works, but it teleports the nearest player, not the one who threw it. I was thinking to add a tag based off the nearest player at the time of throwing and teleport that same player to the end location using /tag @e[type=snowball] add @p, but @p cannot be used at the end of that, sadly. I was wondering if somebody knew how to make that snowball gain a tag based off this nearest player’s name, that’d be great.